# PayPal Adaptive Payments - returnUrl displays in Lightbox IFrame

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal's Adaptive Payments "Pay" method.  Everything seems to be working fine with the lightbox appearing and the payment process completing.  I also receive my IPN on completion.  However when the user presses Close after payment my returnURL is displayed in the IFrame rather than the main window behind it.

I'm stuck fixing this.  The script PayPal provides for post transaction closes the lightbox iframe correctly, but this is where the completion page is so the user simply returns to my checkout page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This page has provided the required information:

http://www.digitalgoodsexpresscheckout.com/PayPal/Articles/DigitalGoodsExpressCheckout/DigiGoodsEC.html